# Conventions in DB,should I use fluent Nhibernate auto mapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a DB with name conventions, there are 4 types of tables:

I can know the table type by its name, each type has its own conventions and there are stuff that related to all of them.

Is this the classic case for fluent nhibernate auto mapping? should I be aware of something?

Should I use the hbm xml mapping?

Comment: I don't see how a naming convention for a relational schema has anything to do with the choice of NHibernate, fluent or otherwise.  Should we be aware of something?  Please explain your reasoning.

Comment: Auto mapping in its core is convention based, example, if you have 100 tables with 'id' column you don't need to write it 100 times (this is a simple case), more stuff can be a version columns, different handling for mapping relations and some other cool stuff. My db has a lot of conventions, but has 4 kinds of tables each with it's own conventions. I wanna know if it's still recommended to use fluent nhibernate

Comment: I think this will work, the only difference is that your conventions will need to implment the IConventionAcceptance interface as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certantly, automapping works better with a project done from scratch, which isn't your case.

Anyway, Fluent NHibernate provides a decent API to implement your own naming convetions, so you can get these automappings with your existing database schema (look doc at the middle of this wiki article):
http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping